# Alien Animal Headed Foreign Legion misfits take on the military

Tags: story-identification

It was a story about some rich kid officer that buys his way through the worst the military can send his way after he is put in command of a group of alien misfits in some sort of foreign legion. The tale takes place somewhere other than Earth. The cover had a bunch of uniformed animal headed soldiers drinking in a bar. There were at least two books, so it could be a series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hear and obey/take advice. :-)

[Phule's Company by Robert Asprin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phule%27s_Company_%28series%29)? The book follows the comedic events as Willard J. Phule, the rich son of a millionaire arms manufacturer, reforms a group of misfits in the Space Legion, a fictional organization similar to the French Foreign Legion, into an "elite fighting force".

Comment: A timely answer if ever I saw one. Thanks.

Comment: The cover of one edition is similar to your description- if you squint.

Comment: The *Phule's Paridise* cover is the one I remember. Bar, cafe, diner...